# Use grep to parse column names

Tags: r, regex

There is a data frame from which I want to delete all columns in which there is the string  `XFL` or `XST` in the colname. The colname is not exclusively `XFL` but can be something like `ktel_XFL` or `ktel_XST`. I know there has to be some way to do that with `grep`?

Comment: I saw by chance that you haven't accepted any of your 13 questions so far. It's good practice to do that once your question is answered by clicking the check mark beside the answer you liked best (it will turn green afterwards).

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
df <- df[, !grepl("XFL|XST", names(df)), drop = FALSE]
```

Since there is no reproducible example in the question, you can check it out using the iris data set:

```
data(iris)
# delete any column that contains "Sepal" or "Petal":
iris[, !grepl("Sepal|Petal", names(iris)), drop = FALSE]
#       Species
#1       setosa
#2       setosa
#3       setosa
#4       setosa
#5       setosa
#...
```

Comment: but my colnmaes are not only XFL...they are part of a longer s name

Comment: Did you try it? Since I used `grepl` it will also match column names that that have names that include XFS but are not only XFS or XST

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach:

```
# create a cloumn index
idx <- grep("X(FL|ST)", colnames(dat), invert = TRUE)
# filter columns
dat[idx]
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Another one through negative lookahead assertion.

```
df[grep("^(?!.*X(FL|ST)).*", colnames(df), perl=T)]
```

Comment: May I ask what's the difference between your approach with `"^(?!.*X(FL|ST)).*"` vs Sven's approach with just `"X(FL|ST)"`?

Comment: @docendodiscimus i do the negative part within the regex itself. But does it through the external parameter `invert = TRUE`